# How can I use tf.summary.text properly?

Tags: python, text, tensorflow, summary, tensorboard

I'm trying to use this function to write a log text to the Tensorboard log file but I'm getting some troubles with this.

I want to write a list (or np.array) that contains strings. I can't just pass this as it's not a tensor, so how can I do this?

What I'm trying:

```
hyperparameters = ["learning_rate=1","batch_size=50","optimizer=Adagrad"]

summary_op = tf.summary.text("hyperparameters info", hyperparameters)
summary = session.run(summary_op )

writer.add_summary(summary)
```

Please take acount that that I already defined a FileWriter and I'm already running a session.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm not sure about this but  you need to set your hyperparameters as  a tensor of string   ?

Comment: @Engine No, it's just an example. I need to log a list containing strings. In my case I have a list with several not-hardcoded string items.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a tensor like that:

```
hyperparams = np.array(["learning_rate=1","batch_size=50","optimizer=Adagrad"])
hyperparams_tensor = tf.constant(hyperparams)

#Or Directly use the tensor, there is no need for np.array() or list
#hyperparams_tensor = tf.constant(["learning_rate=1","batch_size=50","optimizer=Adagrad"])

summary_op = tf.summary.text("hyperparameters info", hyperparams_tensor)
summary = session.run(summary_op)

writer.add_summary(summary)
```